# Where do i store images and how do i get them in codename one new gui

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

[image: Code name one picking image]

I don't know where to store images and how to get the images by their id and this new gui is good but there are no tutorials on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The images are stored in the resource file (`theme.res`) which lets you use features such as multi-image (an image that [adapts to DPI](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-dpi-explained.html).

You can edit the resource file via CSS or the designer (depending on your configuration). Assuming you didn't enable CSS you can use the following toolbar option to add an images directly from the GUI builder.

Notice these 3 icons on the top right area:

[image]

When you hover over them you should see the following tooltips:

- Add Image
- Add Multi Image
- Set Multi Image Import DPI

They all do what you expect. The last one shows you this dialog:

[image]

Here you can define the density to which you designed the image you're importing. That way it will be logically scaled to all the other densities so an image designed for a 600ppi device will look similar on a 300ppi device (ppi == Pixels Per Inch).

I agree the UX should be improved here so I added [an RFE](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2934) for fixing this in a future update.